# Join us in our inn or join us at our inn

Tags: word-choice

Join us in Hawaii at our bed and breakfast. 
Join us in Hawaii in our bed and breakfast.
Is one right and one wrong or are both acceptable?

Join us at our romantic bed and breakfast.
Join us in our romantic bed and breakfast.

Thanks to anyone that comments!

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the Dictionary, we get the following definitions:

> **at**: expressing location or arrival in a particular place or position
>
> **in**: expressing the situation of something that is or appears to be enclosed or surrounded by something else

'In' is used to denote a more general location and 'at' is used for a more specific location, for example:

- I'm in the Empire State  Building, at the front desk
- I'm in New York, at the conference
- I'm in New York, at the Empire State Building

However, also take note the difference when in is used to indicate inside, for example:

- I'm in the elevator = I'm inside the elevator
- I'm at the elevator = I'm near the elevator

EDIT: Join us in Hawaii at our bed and breakfast would be more suitable, as explained in the examples above.

Comment: I agree with Ronald and Robert. You guys covered it, pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the preferred usage is, "Join us in Hawaii at our bed and breakfast." At is used for specific locations; in is used for something inside an enclosed area. Here is a clarifying example" "He is staying in New York at The Waldorf Astoria in room 1349." I cite this source: http://www.engvid.com/prepositions-of-place-at-on-in-grammar/ . Join us. Where? At our romantic bed and breakfast. At the Waldorf Astoria. At the romantic Waldorf Astoria, in Room 1349, in New York. At the New York location, not at the New Orleans location.  The Waldorf owns properties both in New York and in New Orleans.